# Multi cursor in oracle function

Tags: oracle, cursor

I want to create an oracle function that get the user_id as param and return varchar2 that contain the e-mail text for the books that the user take from the library and didn't return them back, my email text that I want is:
"hello "
You should return this books:
1 <BOOK_NAME> that taken at 
2. ....

This is what I wrote so far

```
create or replace function get_un_recived_books(param_client_id in number) return varchar2 is
  Result varchar2(2000);
 

      
   cursor cur_book is 
      select * from hashala natural join client natural join all_books natural join book
           where 
                    recived =0
                    and recived_date is null
                    and clientid= param_client_id          
                    and taken_date <   add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -3);
                    
        begin
               FOR b IN cur_book LOOP

        Result:= 'book  ' || b.book_name;
  END LOOP;
 
                  
  return(Result);
end;
```

I have 3 problems

1. how can i return all the books and not the last one (like += in c)
2. for the client name do I need to add another cursor, can I do it?
3. how to pass the value from the original query

   ```
     select get_un_recived_books(!!!ADD HERE THE CLIENID!!!), clientid from hashala natural join client natural join all_books natural join
   ```

   book
   where
   recived =0
   and recived_date is null

   ```
                    and taken_date <   add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -3);
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's sample schema to illustrate *how* you might do that. Read comments within code.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  5    retval   varchar2(4000);
  6  begin
  7    -- department name (in your case, client name)
  8    select dname
  9      into l_dname
 10      from dept
 11      where deptno = par_deptno;
 12
 13    -- loop through employees in PAR_DEPTNO (in your case,
 14    -- books client borrowed)
 15    for cur_r in (select ename, hiredate
 16                  from emp
 17                  where deptno = par_deptno
 18                 )
 19    loop
 20      -- this is what you're missing: "retval := retval || ..."
 21      retval := retval || 'Name: ' || cur_r.ename ||
 22               ', borrowed on ' || to_char(cur_r.hiredate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || chr(10);
 23    end loop;
 24
 25    retval := 'Hello, ' || l_dname ||chr(10) ||
 26              'you borrowed the following books and didn''t return them yet.' || chr(10) ||
 27              retval;
 28    return retval;
 29  end;
 30  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello, ACCOUNTING
you borrowed the following books and didn't return them yet.
Name: CLARK, borrowed on 09.06.1981
Name: KING, borrowed on 17.11.1981
Name: MILLER, borrowed on 23.01.1982


SQL>
```

---

If you - as you said - want to pass the ID "dynamically", just include it into the function. Something like this (I'm retrieving data for departments 10 and 30, for everyone who works as a clerk):

```
SQL> select f_test(d.deptno)
  2  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where d.deptno in (10, 30)
  4    and e.job = 'CLERK';

F_TEST(D.DEPTNO)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello, SALES
you borrowed the following books and didn't return them yet.
Name: ALLEN, borrowed on 20.02.1981
Name: WARD, borrowed on 22.02.1981
Name: MARTIN, borrowed on 28.09.1981
Name: BLAKE, borrowed on 01.05.1981
Name: TURNER, borrowed on 08.09.1981
Name: JAMES, borrowed on 03.12.1981

Hello, ACCOUNTING
you borrowed the following books and didn't return them yet.
Name: CLARK, borrowed on 09.06.1981
Name: KING, borrowed on 17.11.1981
Name: MILLER, borrowed on 23.01.1982


SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more code to answer the question. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) function to achieve this. This task can be solved in pure SQL via [view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30), which will not produce child cursors compared to function invocation. You just need to filter it if you wish to select individual clients.

However you can also put the same text in a function if you wish, which also doesn't require any loops. Because from Oracle 12C and above you may extend `varchar2` up to 32767 bytes with [`MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C) parameter, which removes the boundary of `varchar2` in SQL compared to PL/SQL.

Both the examples are below:

> ```
> create table client
> as
> select
>   level as id
>   , 'Client ' || level as name
> from dual
> connect by level < 10
> ```

> ```
> create table book
> as
> select
>   level as id
>   , 'Book ' || level as name
> from dual
> connect by level < 100
> ```

> ```
> create table borrowed_book
> as
> select
>   trunc(level / 4) + 1 as client_id
>   , level as book_id
>   , add_months(sysdate, -mod(level, 11)) as dt
>   , case mod(level, 4) when 1 then 1 else 0 end as received
> from dual
> connect by level < 60
> ```

> ```
> create view v_reminder
> as
>   select
>     bb.client_id,
>     c.name as client_name,
>     'Hello, ' || max(c.name) || '!'
>     || chr(10) || chr(10)
>     || 'You should return this books:' || chr(10)
>     || listagg(b.name || ' borrowed on ' || to_char(bb.dt, 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), chr(10))
>          within group(order by bb.dt desc, bb.book_id) as rem
>
>   from borrowed_book bb
>     join client c
>       on bb.client_id = c.id
>     join book b
>       on bb.book_id = b.id
>   where bb.received = 0
>     and bb.dt < add_months(sysdate, -3)
>   group by bb.client_id, c.name
> ```

> ```
> create or replace function f_get_reminder(p_client_id in int, p_dt_offset in int default 3)
> return varchar2
> as
>   res varchar2(32000);
> begin
>   select
>     'Hello, ' || max(c.name) || '!'
>     || chr(10) || chr(10)
>     || 'You should return this books:' || chr(10)
>     || listagg(b.name || ' borrowed on ' || to_char(bb.dt, 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), chr(10))
>          within group(order by bb.dt desc, bb.book_id)
>     
>     into res
>   from borrowed_book bb
>     join client c
>       on bb.client_id = c.id
>     join book b
>       on bb.book_id = b.id
>   where bb.received = 0
>     and bb.dt < add_months(sysdate, -p_dt_offset)
>     and bb.client_id = p_client_id
>   /*Added this line to get NULL as output, because aggregate function
>   without group by always returns a row even for empty input dataset*/
>   group by bb.client_id
>   ;
>     
>   return res;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> select
>   c.id
>   , c.name
>   , f_get_reminder(c.id) as rem
> from client c
> ```
>
> | ID | NAME | REM |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Client 1 | *null* |
> | 2 | Client 2 | Hello, Client 2! You should return this books: Book 4 borrowed on 27-Feb-2021 Book 6 borrowed on 27-Dec-2020 Book 7 borrowed on 27-Nov-2020 |
> | 3 | Client 3 | Hello, Client 3! You should return this books: Book 8 borrowed on 27-Oct-2020 Book 10 borrowed on 27-Aug-2020 |
> | 4 | Client 4 | Hello, Client 4! You should return this books: Book 15 borrowed on 27-Feb-2021 |
> | 5 | Client 5 | Hello, Client 5! You should return this books: Book 16 borrowed on 27-Jan-2021 Book 18 borrowed on 27-Nov-2020 Book 19 borrowed on 27-Oct-2020 |
> | 6 | Client 6 | Hello, Client 6! You should return this books: Book 20 borrowed on 27-Sep-2020 |
> | 7 | Client 7 | Hello, Client 7! You should return this books: Book 26 borrowed on 27-Feb-2021 Book 27 borrowed on 27-Jan-2021 |
> | 8 | Client 8 | Hello, Client 8! You should return this books: Book 28 borrowed on 27-Dec-2020 Book 30 borrowed on 27-Oct-2020 Book 31 borrowed on 27-Sep-2020 |
> | 9 | Client 9 | Hello, Client 9! You should return this books: Book 32 borrowed on 27-Aug-2020 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41eb6982dc3938496945a69a72c576f9)*